# fgets how to read int

Tags: c

please fgets function how to read int ?

and one more question scanf how to like fgets press enter then continue next step?

thanks!

Comment: How is this `int` represented in whatever file you're trying to read? (Show us an example: is this simple text, or something more complex?). `scanf` will, like `fgets`, wait for the user to press enter, if you're reading from `stdin` (and you've not modified it otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

If you use fgets, you would need to use sscanf() after that to read integers.

Comment: `atoi()`, `strtol()` and similar are enough to read numbers from strings.