# I'm trying to create a program with a loop that prompts the user to enter data in the array elements

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a program with a loop that prompts the user to enter data in the array elements. And when the user no longer can enter data, print to screen the data entered in a last in, first out order.

And this is my attempt...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Name_Age
{
    char Name[10];
    int Age;
};

void printMe(struct Name_Age info)
{
    printf("Name: %s\n", info.Name);
    printf("Age:  %d\n", info.Age);
}

int main()
{
    int size = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
    struct Name_Age * array_ptr = (struct Name_Age*)malloc((size + 1)* sizeof(struct Name_Age));
    struct Name_Age myInfo = *array_ptr;

    printf("Enter size of array: ");
    scanf("%d\n", size);

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        printf("Enter Name: \n");
        scanf("%s\n", myInfo.Name);
        printf("Enter Age: \n");
        scanf("%d\n", myInfo.Age);
    }

    printMe(myInfo);

    return 0;

};
```

Comment: So what exactly is your error....? Also, you need to remove that semicolon after your ending brace.

Comment: I would look into using `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`, also you might want to specify a size for `%s` to prevent overflow, especially since your `Name` variable is so small. And `scanf()` takes a `pointer` to the variable where it will store stuff, so since `myInfo,Name` will decay into a pointer to the first element in that array, you're fine for that case, but `scanf("%d\n", myInfo.Age);` must be changed to `scanf("%d\n", &myInfo.Age);`. I've made the update in my edit, along with some other stuff to make your answer more technically correct.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @Rasta: Your edit is invalid, and I've voted to reject it. It is a violation of the policy here to substantially change the code in a question other than formatting, and you've altered the meaning and intent of the code with your edit. Please stop making those sorts of changes; if you continue, your editing privileges will end up being suspended.

Comment: @KenWhite wait what exactly did I change I don't even remember now? I thought I just added the `&` needed for the integer value for `scanf()`?

Comment: @Rasta: You made several changes to the code (including changing *main*), and **any** changes to the code other than formatting are against the guidelines here. Altering the code can hide or change the problem the poster is having. Even the edit of adding `&` is invalid when editing a question. **No code changes other than formatting are permitted.**

Comment: @KenWhite I see, I'm sorry about that. So even removing a cast for return value for `malloc()` is wrong too? I apologize. To change gears a little bit, is it okay to pass a struct to a function as opposed to a pointer to that struct? Does it make a copy of it (if so, I didn't think "pass by value" was even remotely a thing in C)? I know when you pass arrays it really is using pointers automatically, but I really don't know the behavior with structs.

Comment: @Rasta: Yes, A change to **anything** other than formatting (and even those if the language is sensitive to formatting) are prohibited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `scanf("%d", &size)` replace `scanf("%d\n", size)`, put `&size` instead of `size` as argument(You need an address), and put the `malloc` things after this line of code, because you need an exact `size` value before `malloc`. Same thing with all the `scanf` stuffs.

As you want to print out all your input names and ages in order, I changed your code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Name_Age
{
    char Name[10];
    int Age;
};

void printMe(struct Name_Age *infoList, int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = size-1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        printf("Name: %s\n", infoList[i].Name);
        printf("Age:  %d\n", infoList[i].Age);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int size, i;

    printf("Enter size of array: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    struct Name_Age * array_ptr = (struct Name_Age*)malloc(size* sizeof(struct Name_Age));

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        printf("Enter Name: \n");
        scanf("%s", array_ptr[i].Name);
        printf("Enter Age: \n");
        scanf("%d", &array_ptr[i].Age);
    }

    printMe(array_ptr, size);

    return 0;
}
```

Try to test and compare with your code, questions are welcome.

Comment: Change `scanf("%s", &array_ptr[i].Name);` to `scanf("%s", array_ptr[i].Name);`, it is incorrect otherwise because the name of the array is already decaying to a pointer. And also, don't cast the return value of `malloc()`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Comment: @RastaJedi maybe `scanf("%s", &(array_ptr[i].Name))` is clearer, but not `scanf("%s", array_ptr[i].Name)`.

Comment: It's not a matter of what is clearer; it is _incorrect_, because using the name of an array already decays to a pointer to the first element, you are actually taking the memory address of the pointer to the first element. That is **not** what you want to be passing to `scanf()`. Actually, I think you are giving it a pointer to the entire array, and this is wrong because `%s` expects a _pointer to char_, i.e., `char *`, not a pointer to a character array.... (`char (*)[10]`): `warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[10]'`.

Comment: Within the very first 5 examples of any C tutorial/book, they tell you to use `&` for `%d` for `scanf()`, but **NOT** for `%s`. Everyone knows that, and doing so is incorrect (see above); please do not suggest incorrect code to OP.

Comment: This works tremendously! Thank you both! I appreciate the feedback and the explanation :)

Comment: @RastaJedi Yes, you're right, I didn't take enough care about it. I've edited the post, thanks!

Comment: @Wenfeng You're welcome and I'm sorry if I came off sort of brash; that wasn't my intention :). And also +miiworld2 you are welcome :).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fgets` to read strings and cast the string to digits with `atoi`. The storage is not complete, but with my changes you can read to structs and specify the size of the loop (TODO: Save a list of structs so that you actually can print a list of structs that you have specified.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Name_Age {
    char Name[10];
    int Age;
};

void printMe(struct Name_Age info) {
    printf("Name: %s\n", info.Name);
    printf("Age:  %d\n", info.Age);
}

int main() {
    int size = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
    struct Name_Age *array_ptr = malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(struct Name_Age));
    struct Name_Age myInfo = *array_ptr;

    printf("Enter size of array: ");
    char tmp[10];
    fgets(tmp, 10,stdin);
    size = atoi(tmp);
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        printf("Enter Name: ");
        fgets(myInfo.Name, 10,stdin);
        printf("Enter Age: ");
        fgets(tmp, 10,stdin);
        myInfo.Age = atoi(tmp);
    }

    printMe(myInfo);
    return 0;

};
```

**Test**

```
$ ./a.out 
Enter size of array: 2
Enter Name: Superman
Enter Age: 25
Enter Name: Batman
Enter Age: 27
Name: Batman

Age:  27
```

See also this question about fgets [fgets how to read int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374474/fgets-how-to-read-int)

Comment: Sadly we don't use fgets for this particular class. For challenge purposes. But I will keep this in mind for future references. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously using `fgets()` is a much better approach, but making the fewest amount of changes as possible to your code and still achieving your result is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Name_Age
{
    char Name[10];
    int Age;
};

void printMe(struct Name_Age *info);

int main(void)
{
    int size, i;
    struct Name_Age *array_ptr;

    printf("Enter size of array: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    array_ptr = malloc(size * sizeof *array_ptr);

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
            printf("Enter Name: ");
            scanf(" %s", array_ptr[i].Name);
            printf("Enter Age: ");
            scanf("%d", &array_ptr[i].Age);
            printf("\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            printMe(&array_ptr[i]);

    return 0;
}

void printMe(struct Name_Age *info)
{
    printf("Name: %s\n", info->Name);
    printf("Age:  %d\n", info->Age);
}
```

Note that passing the struct by pointer to the function should be faster, note that you don't need the `myInfo` struct; you can just directly modify the elements of the array. Note the space before `%s` in the `scanf()` line, this is to discard any whitespace (including `\n`), this is done automatically for `%d` so it is only necessary for your strings (technically not the first iteration of the loop, but it doesn't fail if no whitespace is found). If you have any questions about why I made the changes I did, please feel free to comment on this answer!

Comment: Definitely add some error checking and input validation. You wouldn't want someone to try to specify a negative number for `size` e.g....

Answer (score 1):

example of fix

```
//struct Name_Age myInfo = *array_ptr;//Not necessary

printf("Enter size of array: ");
scanf("%d", &size);//remove `\n`, add `&`

//To ensure after the size has been determined
struct Name_Age * array_ptr = (struct Name_Age*)malloc(size * sizeof(struct Name_Age));//Cast is not necessary in C

for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    printf("Enter Name: \n");
    scanf("%s", array_ptr[i].Name);//remove `\n`
    printf("Enter Age: \n");
    scanf("%d", &array_ptr[i].Age);//need `&`
}

for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    printMe(array_ptr[i]);
```